# Visual Basic - Check To See If Program Can Edit Registry

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, registry

I am working on a Visual Basic 2008 program that has to edit the computer's registry, but I want to add a way for the program to check to see if it has permission to edit the registry, and if it doesn't, I want it to inform the user. Is there a way to check to see if the program can edit the registry so that the program does not crash if it is not able to carry out its editing?

Thanks in advance for your help! I am willing to try anything that you suggest.

Comment: Just try to read/edit and catch Exceptions.. In this way, you could also catch other Exceptions (like Not Found Key or whatsoever)

Comment: @Jamby How would you write the code that is in Ken White's comment in Visual Basic? I got lost when I came crying to Google for help.

Comment: Try use http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/